# Is there a way to recover deleted emails from an Outlook PST file?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, restore, pst

A customer has deleted emails from his Junk Email folder, and now we have been asked to recover them from the pst data file.

Is this possible and how to go about it?

Tried using the advice at http://www.runpcrun.com/deleted-emails-outlook-pst, downloaded the Hex Editor as advised, but it immediately stopped working.

Is there another way?

This is Outlook 2007. The .pst file is a couple of GB.

Comment: "it immediately stopped working" What exactly stopped working?

Comment: @Bandit the hex editor

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the PST file and see if there's any previous versions that you can recover.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to edit the pst file before it quit working (you should be able to use any hex editor for making the changes to the file)?.  If so, have you run scanpst.exe?  Also MAKE SURE to back up the pst file before you start messing with it.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/recover-deleted-outlook-e-mail-by-corrupting-the-pst-file/5054599) for more detailed instructions.

I believe scanpst.exe is usually in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use commercial recovery software for Junk email.

You might give a try to the trial version of [Stellar Phoenix Email Recovery Software](http://www.stellarinfo.com/mail-recovery.htm) (I believe that save is disabled in the trial version).