# Recover Outlook PST files

Tags: microsoft-outlook, data-recovery, pst

I have a 6 GB Outlook file that won't load in Outlook any more. I am not sure what recovery options I have available. I downloaded one recovery tool demo which shows some but not all mail messages.

Are there any tools that have worked for you? Can I import the PST files directly into another software?

EDIT: I have tried [scanpst quite](https://www.recoverfilesdata.com/blog/how-to-recover-deleted-items-in-outlook-for-free/) a few times but it fails to recover the file.

Comment: Isn't 6GB above the size limit that Outlook can handle?

Comment: If the PST is unicode, the PST can be larger than 2GB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to recover deleted emails from an Outlook PST file?](http://superuser.com/questions/286144/is-there-a-way-to-recover-deleted-emails-from-an-outlook-pst-file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried [SCANPST.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287497) - its part of the office install and is used to recover corrupt PST's
Sometimes known as the inbox repair tool
The common install path is

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12

Answer (score 2):

See the official Microsoft page for some more info on this and a possible solution using Outlook 2007:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932086

There's also a bunch of free/commercial tools for splitting PST files, e.g:

http://www.splitpstfile.com/

Comment: The PST file splitter should come in very handy! At least now I can divide and conquer.

Answer (score 1):

Always try ScanPst.exe first, but it doesn't always mange to recover the PST.

At this point you are left with a vast array of commercial options starting at around $70, I've had success with recoverytoolbox.com

But your experience will obviously vary.  The recovery process will take a LONG time (5-10 hours) due to the size of your PST file - in the future you may consider archiving it to make maintenance on the file quicker!

PS Since 2003 the maximum size for a .pst is 20GB